# The infinity version of Blumenthal's 0-1 law

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, brownian-motion

Blumenthal's 0-1 law states that on the space of continuous maps with domain $[0, \infty)$ with the appropriate (Wiener) measure making the coordinate maps Brownian motions starting at $x$, any event depending only on the germ $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_0^+$ of infinitessimal events is of trivial measure.  Supposedly, the same is true of tail events.  But everybody I've seen and textbooks all seem only to make an argument based on looking at the transformed Brownian $tB(1/t)$.  Okay, I see where the argument is going.  Problem is, nobody said Blumenthal's 0-1 law holds for abstract Brownian motions.  I've only seen the infinitessimal Blumenthal proven for the case where the Brownian motion is as above, with that space, that measure, and the coordinate maps as the stochastic process.  But the $tB(1/t)$ are no longer coordinate maps on the Wiener space.  Instead, we have kept the old measure, and changed the RVs to something else to invert the process.  This leads to an earlier question of mine (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383497/facts-about-brownian-motions-and-markov-chains-on-concrete-constructions), which would probably be answered by any answer to this question.  How do you generalize facts about this concrete Brownian to general Brownians? (Stochastic processes on any space with independent Gaussian increments which are continuous a.s. in the weak sense that although the continuity points may not form a measurable set, they contain a measurable set that is of probability 1.)

I feel like I must be asking something that is not a mathematical grammatically complete sentence or something.  Every time I ask anybody this family of questions, I never hear anything that makes sense to me.  So I must be totally lost in some really bad way.  It seems to me like everybody should be asking "Where is the justification for the change of representation of this BM while still using things only applying to the original construction." but the fact that not even 1 textbook addresses this question leads me to believe I have a gross misunderstanding somewhere.  Please help!

Comment: Is it that I've gotten to specialized enough knowledge that there aren't enough people anymore for me to assume that any compelling question will always be asked and investigated thoroughly?  I'm really stumped by why I can't simply Google search this question and get a ton of hits because it's not even a subtle detail that is missing from proofs in a number of sources.  Or are people just happy to assume this?  I'm so confused...

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're missing here is Levy's characterisation of Brownian motion.

If $X_t$ is a continuous local martingale and $X^2_t - t$ is also a local martingale then $X_t$ is a Brownian motion.

I'll explain a bit more.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F_t, P)$ be some filtered space with  $X_\circ:\Omega\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ 
and let $\left(C^0,\mathscr F_t,\mathbb P\right)$ be Wiener space with "concrete" Brownian motion $\tilde X_\circ$.

If $X_t$ satisfies the martingale characterization above then it is possible to construct a measure on $\Omega\times C^0$ with marginals $P$ and $\mathbb P$ such that $X_t$ and $\tilde X_t$ agree almost surely.

Levy's characterization only shows that if $X_t$ satisfies the assumptions then the finite dimensional distributions agree. (It's a long time since I did all this.) The coupling (the measure on the product space) is done somewhere else and I can't remember where.

The construction of the coupling is rather trivial because the function $X_t$ 
is a member of $C^0$ almost surely. So we can just fix $\tilde X_t = X_t$ almost surely. So formally we define $\mathbb Q$ on $\mathcal F_t\times\mathscr F_t$ such that $$\mathbb Q(A\times B) = P\{\omega\in A: X_t(\omega)\in B\}.$$

So I only need to check that this defines a proper measure, but as the measures agree on finite dimensional distributions $\mathbb Q$ is defined and consistent on the algebra defined by restricting $B$ to cylinder sets.

Therefore by Carathéodory's extension theorem there is a unique probability  measure $\mathbb Q$ satisfying the above and the maginals of $\mathbb Q$ are $P$ and $\mathbb P$ respectively.

What this means is that if I do a little trick, like consider $tB(1/t)$, we get a Wiener space for $tB(1/t)$ to live in automatically.  So if we use a theorem that holds for Wiener space then I've proved something that holds for a process $X_t$ that with probability one agrees with $tB(1/t)$ for every $t$.

This is something that's assumed when we talk about Brownian motion, so it's not often mentioned explicitly, which may be your difficulty.

Comment: I think I can start to see why this might be the way to go.  With a.s. equality in one fixed construction, as opposed to the abstract distributional equality, questions about sigma algebras, continuity a.s., etc. which go beyond the distribution can be preserved.  However, there are a few points I don't understand.  How does one construct the desired measure on the product space?  Is that where the first part of your answer comes in, because I also don't see how the Martingale characterization is used here.  I take it that often times one will use Fubini to pick a fixed $\omega$...

Comment: And then take a slice so you get something that is plainly isomorphic to the wiener space to carry the claim over, namely the wiener space cross $\{\omega\}$.  If any of this is a misunderstanding, please let me know.  BTW I have not asked about the characterization because the details can be found here, for all reading: http://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/04/13/levys-characterization-of-brownian-motion/ but I haven't followed it yet.

Comment: I can't actually remember how it's officially done.  I think the Levy characterization might be a distraction, it looks like Levy just gives you something with the right finite dimensional distributions. You can work out the finite dimensional distributions of $tB(1/t)$ directly so you don't need to use it.  Once you have the right finite dimensional distributions the coupling's pretty easy, I'll add a construction.

Comment: Ah okay I will consider this soon.  But for now, I should note that the finite dimensional distributions and hence the law of the entire family $X_t$ for any abstract Brownian motion $X_t$ is already completely determined from the more standard definition. (Because the standard definition tells you the finite dimensional distributions are multivariate Gaussian and it gives you the mean vector and covariance matrix.)  Perhaps the Levy characterization is worth learning for other purposes though.  Please let me know if you know any.  If relating to martingale is useful, I should learn it.

Comment: The Levy characterisation is definitely worth learning, but the details aren't that important. It's a useful fact to add to your armoury. But anything to do with SDE's uses it, it's the reason $dX_t = A_t d\mathbf B_t + C_t dt$ makes sense as a distribution. Ask your advisor what "The Martingale Problem" is (Not my area so I can't really point you in the right direction).

Comment: As far as this answer is concerned, it looks like you would have been happy with "The finite dimensional distributions agree *blah blah blah* Kolmogorov's Extension Theorem."   So a coupling argument (Creating a joint distribution with some properties I want) was superfluous. The reason I used it was that I couldn't remember any details about Wiener spaces and measures, but I didn't need to because the coupling construction did all he work for me. It might be worth having a look at something called Skorohod's representation theorem which says you can always do that. It's a nice tool to have.

Comment: I'm happy with anything that serves the purpose, but here it seems like your construction is truly needed, because my "Kolmogorov extension" antics only give distributional equality.  That being said, I will scrutinize this and take a look at the Martingale characterization later tonight.

Comment: I've not accepted this yet because I'm still confused.  I think part of that confusion stems from your definition of $mathbb{Q}$.  Is that right?  I think you're trying to define a measure that puts all the "mass on the diagonal." but I don't think this particular choice of definition is well-defined, first of all (cause it's not a prob measure) but it's also not what we want anyway.  I think we're trying to ascend to a product space, but I don't get it.

Comment: There was a typo, so it wasn't well defined.  The idea is indeed to put all the mass on the diagonal. Then in this case we just need to check that $\mathbb Q(\Omega\times B) = \mathbb P(B)$ for cylinder sets $B$.  Which it is with the new definition.